# Generic protocol for basic types

Tags: generics, swift

I've been pondering the possible implementations of string formatting for swift, most of which boil down to "use NSString(format:...)"  That's all well and good, but I wanted a concise and readable format, so I decided to implement something like python's % formatting operator:

```
@infix func % (value:Double, format:String) -> String {
    return NSString(format:format, value)
}
```

This works great for Double's as I can use:

```
println("PI = " + M_PI % "%.3f")
```

which results in:

```
PI = 3.142
```

While I can create 5 of these trivially, I'd like to turn it into a generic function:

```
@infix func %<T> (value:T, format:String) -> String {
    return NSString(format:format, value)
}
```

But that results in the message:

```
Could not find an overload for 'init' that accepts the supplied arguments
```

Reasonable enough, I could be passing in a tuple, or something equally non-objective-C.  (Note that to really do this Python-style, I *want* to pass in a tuple, but that's another matter and beyond the scope of this question)

I tried declaring my own empty protocol and implementing that on Double, but it didn't help at all.

```
protocol NSStringFormattable {}
extension Double : NSStringFormattable {}

@infix func % <T:NSStringFormattable> (value:T, format:String) -> String {
    return NSString(format:format, value)
}
```

I could obviously do something like add a format function to each class and then just define the operator in terms of the format function, but in many ways that's not any better than just defining 5 different operator overloads.

```
protocol NSStringFormattable {
    func format(format:String) -> String
}

extension Double : NSStringFormattable {
    func format(format:String) -> String {
        return NSString(format:format, self)
    }
}

@infix func % <T:NSStringFormattable> (value:T, format:String) -> String {
    return value.format(format)
}
```

How can I restrict T to only those types that can be passed to `NSString(format:...)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're very close, but you don't need a fixed-length tuple. That's what's causing your headaches. Just use an array instead.

```
@infix func % (values:CVarArg[], format:String) -> String {
  return NSString(format:format, arguments:getVaList(values))
}

[M_PI, 6] % "%.3f->%d"
==> "3.142->6"

[M_PI, M_PI_2] % "%.3f %.3f"
==> "3.142 1.571"
```

Of course this is highly type-unsafe because it's an unchecked printf as you say.

BTW, this even works with mixed-type stuff, and with non-literals:

```
let x = 1
let y = 1.5
let z = "yes"

[x, y, z] % "%d, %.2f, %@"
==> "1, 1.50, yes"
```

I don't know if that part is going to be fragile, however. Mixed-type literals are promoted to `NSArray`, which seems a dangerous thing to do automatically, so they may change it. But `NSArray` is acceptable as a `CVarArg[]`.

Note that not all types can be converted this way. Characters currently cannot for instance. You can overcome this by extending them to do so:

```
extension Character : CVarArg {
  func encode() -> Word[] {
    var result = Word[]()
    let s = String(self)
    for c in s.unicodeScalars {
      result.append(Word(c.value))
    }
    return result
  }
}

let c:Character = "c"

["I", c, 2*3] % "%@, %lc, %d"
==> "I, c, 6"
```

I'm wondering if there's an easier way to write `encode()`, but I'm not sure yet. Hopefully a Character encoding will be provided by Swift in the future. But the lesson here is that arbitrary types could be given an `encode` and be formatted.

```
class Car {
  let make = "Ford"
}

extension Car : CVarArg {
  func encode() -> Word[] {
    return NSString(string:self.make).encode()
  }
}

let car = Car()

[car] % "%@"
```

The lesson here is that you can turn arbitrary things into a `CVarArg` or into any protocol, via extensions.

Comment: True, this is probably the best approach for the multiple argument case.  The key to the whole thing was finding CVarArg though :)

Answer (score 2):

Found it!

```
@infix func % (value:CVarArg, format:String) -> String {
    return NSString(format:format, value)
}
```

This single function allows for:

```
5 % "%04x"

3.4 % "%.3f"

M_PI % "%.3f"

Int64(32) % "%04X"
```

Unfortunately, it also allows for:

```
"String" % "%3.3s"
```

and produces garbage, but welcome to printf without argument type checking

Even further, by defining a set of functions:

```
@infix func % (values:(CVarArg, CVarArg), format:String) -> String {
    return NSString(format:format, values.0, values.1)
}

@infix func % (values:(CVarArg, CVarArg, CVarArg), format:String) -> String {
    return NSString(format:format, values.0, values.1, values.2)
}
```

We can achieve python-like affects:

```
(M_PI, 5) % "%.3f->%d"
```

Kind of ugly to have to define one per tuple-length, but I'll keep hacking on it :)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I have discovered (having gone through the same journey as you), generics are not the solution here, rather multiple overloading (which isn't pretty) -

```
operator infix % { }
@infix func % (format: String, value: Double) -> String {
    return NSString(format:format, value)
}
@infix func % (format: String, value: Float) -> String {
    return NSString(format:format, value)
}
@infix func % (format: String, value: Int) -> String {
    return NSString(format:format, value)
}
```

sorry, reverse parameter order from your example - allows

```
println("PI = %.3f" % M_PI)
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm trying to get around.  Ultimately, I'd like to be able to reproduce the python syntax of `(M_PI, M_PI_2) % "%.3f %.3f"` but that may be expecting way too much :)