# Convert a float into a string in Swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, string

I want to convert a Float into a string.

```
myFloat: Float = 99.0
myString: String
```

How would I convert `myFloat` into a string so I can assign the following code

```
myString = myFloat
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Similar to Connor's answer, you  can do the following to have a little more control about how your Double or Float is dislpayed...

```
let myStringToTwoDecimals = String(format:"%.2f", myFloat)
```

This is basically like stringWithFormat in objC.

Comment: I found this because of the initializer patterns of Swift from ObjectiveC.  `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f and %@", myFloat, @"I do this in my sleep"]` so I assumed that String(format:...) would be a valid initializer

Comment: So, I can have a `println` with format (a little awkward) `println(String(format:"myFloat: %.2f", myFloat))`.

Comment: Yea dude, or you can like... accept change into your life ;) `println("full float value is \(myFloat)")`

Comment: Sometimes I don't want "0.422535211267606", I just want "0.42" so I can read and comprehend the value easily.

Comment: You have reason.  Here is another option, alternate to `println(String(format...))` specifically, David's answer is neat http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24051314/precision-string-format-specifier-in-swift

Answer (score 0):

You can use [String Interpolation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH7-XID_420):

```
var myFloat: Float = 99.0
var myString: String = "\(myFloat)"
```

Comment: Would there be a way then to limit the amount of numbers after the decimal place e.g `99.999` become `99.9` ?

Comment: yes, `var myShortString: String = String(format: "%.2f", myFloat)`