# Swift replacement for Objective-C macro

Tags: macros, swift

I busy rewriting an app in Swift and would like to convert the following macro to Swift code.

```
#define FLOG(format, ...)               NSLog(@"%@.%@ %@", [self class], NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), [NSString stringWithFormat:format, ##__VA_ARGS__])
```

How can I define this as a Swift function such that I can use if anywhere for debug logging purposes, or is there an alternate way to achieve the same thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is probably to take advantage of string interpolation and use:

```
func FLOG(message:String, method:String = __FUNCTION__) {
    println("\(method): \(message)")
}
```

Then you usage is similar to:

```
FLOG("Illegal value: \(value)")
```

Having the method argument default to `__FUNCTION__` means that it will normally be replaced with the calling function name.  Other automatic variables that you could use include `__FILE__`, `__LINE__` and `__COLUMN__`.  Unfortunately `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` is no longer available.

If you want more control over the formatting of the message than string interpolation allows, take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24051314/precision-string-format-specifier-in-swift/24052438#24052438) which demonstrates simplifying access to printf-style formatting in Swift, and would let you do:

```
FLOG("Illegal value: %x" % [value])
```

See also [this post](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=15) from Apple that addresses using `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` in `assert`

Comment: thanks I guess that solves the method part, but how should one define a global function - presumably one can't define a global function like one can define a global variable.  Is it best to define a Singleton class with this (and other helper) function(s) ?

Comment: I would just define this as a global function.  Theres really no reason not to.

Answer (score 0):

Apple's answer to the removal of macros and something new to replace them is that nothing like macros will be available in swift. The closest you can get is to replace #define with a global let variable.

Example: instead of #define CONSTANT 0 you can write let CONSTANT = 0

Whereas, if you want to pass arguments inside a macro, that feature will no longer be available as considered bad programming practice. What you can do instead is create a function.