# Subtracting doubles in a while loop giving strange results

Tags: ios, swift

I am getting an unexpected result and I can't figure out why. In the following Swift code I am subtracting doubles in a while loop and I am expecting the results to always be x.55 since I am only subtracting 5.00 each time, but on the last iteration the result is adding a bunch of additional numbers after the decimal and I can't figure out why.

Can anyone point me in the right direction here? What do I need to do differently if I want the result to always be exact to two decimal places?

Here is the example code:

```
var testValue1 = 5.00
var testValue2 = 15.55

while testValue2 >= testValue1 {
    testValue2 = testValue2 - testValue1
    println("testValue2: \(testValue2)")
}
```

And here is the Console output:
testValue2: 10.55
testValue2: 5.55
testValue2: 0.550000000000001

(I expected the Console output to be: 10.55, 5.55, 0.55)

Comment: this has nothing to do with either Xcode, Swift or iOS. This is standard behavior of floating-point numbers.

Comment: Please take the time to learn about floating point numbers!

Comment: @user3525727: if what you want is show numbers with 2 decimals only, take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24055762/148357)

Comment: As @Antonio  stated: Reducing the precision doesn't lead to better results. Using floats instead of doubles means you get less precise results.

Comment: Wow ok thanks all. My mistake, sorry.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the final solution :)

```
var testValue1 = 5.00
var testValue2 = 15.55

while testValue2 >= testValue1 {
    testValue2 = testValue2 - testValue1
    var s = NSString(format: "%0.2f", testValue2)
    println("testValue2: \(s)")
}
```

*Kudos to Thomas Kilian for letting me know how to implement my logic!*

Comment: Try `let s = NSString(format: "%2.2f", testValue2); println("testValue2: \(s)")`

Comment: What is really needed is to round the number to the desired number of decimal places, not relying on a format or print statement.

Comment: @Zaph Hey , it still serves the purpose as he wants to display the result as 2 decimal places