# FloatValue with 2 decimals from textField

Tags: ios, swift

In my Core Data app I save 3 Floating point numbers from 3 UITexFields. To do that I had to convert them to Strings.

Now the problem is that the values are rounded to `.0`.

How do I do it?

```
nyTankning.liter = (textFieldLiter.text as NSString).floatValue
nyTankning.kronor = (textFieldKronor.text as NSString).floatValue
nyTankning.literpris = (textFieldLiterpris.text as NSString).floatValue
```

Comment: Can you explain what the issue is, I didn't get that. If you don't want the ., convert it to int

Comment: When the value is saved e.g. if I type in 3,14 it is rounded to 3.0. I still want it to be 2 decimals

Comment: possible duplicate of [Precision String Format Specifier In Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24051314/precision-string-format-specifier-in-swift)

Comment: @David the main issue here is the decimal separator as you can see in the comment right above yours

Comment: Is the problem converting floating point numbers in european format?  Ie., using comma instead of period as the decimal separator?  If that's true, make sure you have your locale set properly and use NSNumberFormatter.

Comment: If that is indeed the problem, you can use `localizedStringWithFormat` instead of `stringWithFormat` (on OS-X, it's not available on iOS for some reason)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem there is that you are trying to use a comma "," instead of a period "."

```
struct Number {
    static let formatter = NumberFormatter()
}
extension String {
    var converted: String? {
        return fractionDigits()
    }
    var doubleValue: Double? {
        return Number.formatter.number(from: self)?.doubleValue
    }
    var floatValue: Float? {
        return Number.formatter.number(from: self)?.floatValue
    }
    func fractionDigits(min: Int = 2, max: Int = 2) -> String? {
        Number.formatter.decimalSeparator = "."
        if let result = Number.formatter.number(from: self) {
            Number.formatter.minimumFractionDigits = min
            Number.formatter.maximumFractionDigits = max
            return Number.formatter.string(from: result)
        } else {
            Number.formatter.decimalSeparator = ","
            if let result = Number.formatter.number(from: self) {
                Number.formatter.minimumFractionDigits = min
                Number.formatter.maximumFractionDigits = max
                return Number.formatter.string(from: result)
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

---

```
"1,1222".converted              // "1.12"
"2".converted                   // "2.00"

"1,1222".converted?.doubleValue  // 1.12
"2".converted?.doubleValue       // 2.0

"1,1222".converted?.floatValue   // 1.12000000476837
"2".converted?.floatValue        // 2.0

"1.1222".converted              // "1.12"
"1.1222".converted?.doubleValue  // 1.12
"1.254".converted?.floatValue    // 1.25

"1.254".fractionDigits(min: 1, max: 2) // "1.25"
"1.2".fractionDigits(min: 1, max: 2)   // "1.2"
```

Comment: aha, so the problem is the decimal keypad?

Comment: the problem is that you have to indicate the decimalSeparator the default decimalSeparator is a period and it ignores everything after the first character that is not a number.

Comment: It works in the Simulato, but not on my iPhone. Can it be a Beta bug (iOS 8.2 Beta 4)?

Comment: Feel free to open another question describing your problem

Comment: I would if I had enough rep ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `NSString(format: "%.02f", nyTanking.liter)`