# Using Swift how to convert a string to a number

Tags: ios, swift, nsnumberformatter

I am getting values back from a web service that gives me back prices in a string format, this is put into a Dictionary, so I get prices back as "1.5000" for example, which is obviously 1.50 in currency.  However for the life of me I cannot get anything to work in Swift to format this correctly.  In most other languages you can do this in a couple of seconds, so I'm getting a bit frustrated with something that is so simple.

Here's my test code:

```
    var testnumber = "1.5000"
    let n = NSNumberFormatter()
    n.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterStyle.DecimalStyle
    n.maximumFractionDigits = 2
    n.minimumFractionDigits = 2
    let returnNumber = n.numberFromString(testnumber)
    println("Returned number is \(returnNumber)")
```

This prints out in debug "number is Optional(1.5)" not 1.50!

I have changed NSNumberFormatterStyle.DecimalStyle to NSNumberFormatterStyle.CurrencyStyle as I thought that may do it for me as the returned number is a currency anyway, but that gives me back in debug "Returned number is nil" - which is even more confusing to me!

I have tried using maximumIntegerDigits and minimumIntegerDigits, setting locales using n.locale = NSLocale.currentLocale(), setting formatWidth, setting paddingPosition and paddingCharacter but nothing helps, I either get nil back to 1.5.

All I ultimately need to do is convert a string to a float or a currency value, and ensure there are 2 decimal places, and I can't believe it's this hard to accomplish!

Any help would be very gratefully received.

Comment: What about `let returnNumber = n.numberFromString(testnumber)?.floatValue()`?

Comment: Nope that still returns 1.5

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27931702/floatvalue-with-2-decimals-from-textfield/27932153#27932153

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are printing a number not a string

**Xcode 11.4 • Swift 5.2 or later**

```
extension Formatter {
    static let usCurrency: NumberFormatter = {
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.locale = .init(identifier: "en_US")
        formatter.numberStyle = .currency
        return formatter
    }()
}
```

---

```
extension String {
    var double: Double? { Double(self) }
    var usCurrencyFormatted: String {
        Formatter.usCurrency.string(for: double) ?? Formatter.usCurrency.string(for: 0) ?? ""
    }
}
```

---

```
"1.1222".usCurrencyFormatted           // "$1.12"
"2".usCurrencyFormatted                // "$2.00"
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is about `numberFromString` returning an optional - so you have to unwrap before printing. Just to be safe, you can use optional binding:

```
if let returnNumber = n.numberFromString(testnumber) {
    println("Returned number is \(returnNumber)")
}
```

otherwise if it's ok for the app to crash if the optional is nil (in some cases this is a wanted behavior if the optional is expected to always contain a non nil value) just use forced unwrapping:

```
let returnNumber = n.numberFromString(testnumber)!
println("Returned number is \(returnNumber)")
```

That fixes the unwanted `"Optional(xx)"` text. As for formatting a float/double number, there are probably several ways of doing it - the one I would use is c-like string formatting, available via `NSString`:

```
let formattedNumber = NSString(format: "%.2f", returnNumber)
println("Returned number is \(formattedNumber)")
```

Use [String Format Specifiers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html) as reference if you want to know more about format specifiers.

Comment: @Dave: 1.5 and 1.50 are exactly the same numbers.

Comment: I am aware that 1.5 and 1.50 are the same number, but it needs to be formatted correctly to the user.  Who has ever seen a price give to a user as $1.5 rather than $1.50.  That's all I am trying to do.

Comment: @Dave: Well, in your question you said that you want to *"... convert a string to a float"* and 1.5 is a float. If you want to present it as "$1.50" then you have to convert the floating point number back to a string with a suitable number formatter.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably just use the `NSNumberFormatter` that you just created.

```
let returnNumber = n.stringFromNumber(n.numberFromString(testnumber))
```

`returnNumber` will now be of type `String`.

Answer (score 0):

The following returns to 2 decimal places for me in playgrounds. May be of some help to you. Uses NSNumberFormatter and then unwraps the optional

```
let testnumber: String = "1.50000"
let numberFormatter = NSNumberFormatter()
let number  = numberFormatter.numberFromString(testnumber)
if let final = number?.floatValue {
    println("Returned number is " + String(format: "%.2f", final))
}
```