# Error When Converting JSON String To Number Using Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, string

I have a basic question to convert string to number in Swift. I found a good stack overflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27991601/using-swift-how-to-convert-a-string-to-a-number) that helps me convert a JSON string to a number, but **I get an error when I try to add or subtract the values.**

I am sure I am missing something obvious!

Phil

Error: Referencing operator function '-' on 'BinaryInteger' requires that 'NSNumber' conform to 'BinaryInteger'

```
func red2G()->String {
        let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
        
        // Prev Close
        let number1  = numberFormatter.number(from: pricesAlpha?.globalQuote.prevClose ?? "0.000")
        if let final1 = number1?.floatValue {
        print("Returned number is " + String(format: "%.2f", final1))
        }
        
        // Open
        let number2  = numberFormatter.number(from: pricesAlpha?.globalQuote.open ?? "0.000")
        if let final2 = number2?.floatValue {
        print("Returned number is " + String(format: "%.2f", final2))
        }
        
        // Price
        let number3  = numberFormatter.number(from: pricesAlpha?.globalQuote.price ?? "0.000")
        if let final3 = number3?.floatValue {
        print("Returned number is " + String(format: "%.2f", final3))
        }
        
        return String(number3-number2)
     }
```

I simplified the function based on the proposed answer:

```
    func load(symbolName:String) {
        self.symbolName = symbolName
    }
    
    func red2G()->String {
        let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
        
        // Prev Close
        let prevClose  = numberFormatter.number(from: pricesAlpha?.globalQuote.prevClose ?? "0.000")?.floatValue
        
        // Open
        let openPrice  = numberFormatter.number(from: pricesAlpha?.globalQuote.open ?? "0.000")?.floatValue
        
        // Price
        let currentPrice  = numberFormatter.number(from: pricesAlpha?.globalQuote.price ?? "0.000")?.floatValue
        
        return String((openPrice ?? 0.00) - (prevClose ?? 0.00) - (currentPrice ?? 0.00))
}
```

The values are based on this JSON Dictionary

```
struct GlobalQuote: Codable {
    let globalQuote: PriceAlpha
    
    enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case globalQuote = "Global Quote"
    }
}

struct PriceAlpha: Codable {
    let symbol: String
    let open: String
    let high: String
    let low: String
    let price: String
    let volume: String
    let tradingDay: String
    let prevClose: String
    let change: String
    let pctChange: String
    
    enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case symbol = "01. symbol"
        case open = "02. open"
        case high = "03. high"
        case low = "04. low"
        case price = "05. price"
        case volume = "06. volume"
        case tradingDay = "07. latest trading day"
        case prevClose = "08. previous close"
        case change = "09. change"
        case pctChange = "10. change percent"
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your JSON string?

Comment: "Error: Referencing operator function"  At what line?

Comment: That post will return a `String` not a `Double` or `Float`. if you just want to convert `String` to `Double` just use `Double(yourString)`

Comment: Hi Leo, I tried the Double() as you suggested, it works! However, I still cannot perform basic math because a new error: Value of optional type 'Double?' must be unwrapped to a value of type 'Double'". Example: `let currentPrice = Double(pricesAlpha?.globalQuote.price ?? "0.00")`. The error occurs on this math: `return String(openPrice - prevClose)`

Comment: Update: using guard let and else closure, I was able to solve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

`NSNumber` is a object wrapper around an actual integer or float or whatever. You see in your code where you call `floatValue`? That gets an actual number that you can do math with. Keep `final3` and `final2` around outside of their `if` statements and do the math on that.

That said, you should almost certainly implement custom decoding and encoding in `PriceAlpha` so that the struct already contains values in the correct semantic type (e.g. `Float`) instead of `String`. But for financial information, you’ll actually want `Decimal`, not `Float`.

Comment: Thanks for hint, I will move the final2 and final3 outside the if statement. I would also LOVE to convert the prices to float or decimal at decode time, it seems to be super complicated based on the examples I found on the stack overflow!

Comment: Unfortunately, I receive a new error based on the simplified function I posted above. Error: Value of optional type 'Float?' must be unwrapped to a value of type 'Float'. I just want to do basic math on the prices :(