# How to format a decimal number (double) to a string with a certain precision and based of the default Locale?

Tags: swift

So far I was formatting my doubles into Strings like this:

```
String(format:"%0.4f", rate)
```

Problem: the decimal separator is always `.` while in France for example we use `,`

Then I used an `NSNumberFormatter` with `numberStyle = .DecimalStyle` but then I cannot choose the precision of 4 digits as I did before.

What are my solutions?

Thanks

Comment: NSNumberFormatter has *many* properties to control the output format. Did you try setting minimumFractionDigits/maximumFractionDigits ?

Comment: Yes it was actually what I was looking for and couldn't find the keyword "fraction". Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27932153/2303865

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a `NSNumberFormatter` and set both the minimum and maximum
*fraction digits* to use:

```
let fmt = NSNumberFormatter()
fmt.maximumFractionDigits = 4
fmt.minimumFractionDigits = 4
let output = fmt.stringFromNumber(123.123456789)!
println(output) // 123,1235 (for the German locale)
```

Update for **Swift 3** (and later):

```
let fmt = NumberFormatter()
fmt.maximumFractionDigits = 4
fmt.minimumFractionDigits = 4
let output = fmt.string(from: 123.123456789)!
print(output) // 123,1235 (for the German locale)
```

Comment: `NSNumberFormatter` has renamed to `NumberFormatter` in swift 4

Comment: @Johnny: You are right (and actually already in Swift 3), thanks for the notice!