# Double String formatting madness

Tags: swift, formatting, double

I have the following in playground:

```
let a:CGFloat = 1.23
let b:Double = 3.45
let c:Float = 6.78
String(format: "(%2.2f|%2.2f|%2.2f)",a,b,c) // prints "(3.45|6.78|0.00)"
let d = NSMakePoint(9.87,6.54)
String(format: "(%2.2f|%2.2f)",d.x,d.y) // prints "(0.00|0.00)"
```

So why is `c:Float` rendered as `0.00`. I possibly need something else than `f` (Apples docu on this formatting function is - to be polite - quite thin with a limes going to zero).

BUT: Why is the `CGFloat` in the first place rendered correctly while the two `CGFloat`s inside the `NSPoint` get rendered as `0.00`?

And no: it's not a duplicate of [Precision String Format Specifier In Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24051314/precision-string-format-specifier-in-swift) and its pendant.

P.S.

```
String(format: "(%2.2f|%2.2f)",Double(d.x),d.y) // prints  "(9.87|0.00)"
```

which is a work around but no explanation.

And a PPS: Isn't `%2.2f` supposed to print " 9.87" instead of "9.87" (2 places for leading digits? It seems to ignore the number. Specifying `%02.2f` also prints "9.87" rather than "09.87"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CGFloat isn't a float or a double, it is its own struct.  If you want the double or float value of a CGFloat (which is dependent on the architecture being 32 or 64 but, then you can access it with a.native.  In other words try:

```
String(format: "(%2.2f|%2.2f|%2.2f)",a.native,b,c)
```

You'd see similar behavior if you tried to pass other non-float or non-double arguments to the %f formatter.  For example:

```
var str = "Hello, playground"
String(format: "%2.2f|%2.2f|%2.2f", arguments: [str,b,c])
```

would result in "3.45|6.78|0.00".  It appears to be looking for another float in your arguments to satisfy the last %f, and defaults to 0.00

As for the PPS.  %2.2F is two decimal place and at least 2 total digits.  If you wanted two digits minimum before the decimal, you'd want `%5.2f`.  5 because the decimal itself takes a place.