# Format number from 0.5 to display 0.50 with swift

Tags: swift, string-formatting

So imagine I want my code to count in 0.25, and I want it to be like: 0.00, 0.25, 0.50... but it's currently like: 0, 0.25, 0.5...
  That part of my code like this:

```
if (Score >= 0 && Score < 10.00){
    Score += 0.25
    HighScoreLabel.text = "The Score is \(Score)"
}
```

Comment: That is not rounding. That is formatting.

Comment: Looks "kinda". I wonder if that's the issue... Why do you want the extra zero anyway?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Precision String Format Specifier In Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24051314/precision-string-format-specifier-in-swift)

Comment: Please don't use capital letters for variable names.

Answer (score 4):

```
let score = 0.5
let stringDisplay = String(format: "%.02f", score)
println("The Score is \(stringDisplay)")   // "The Score is 0.50"
```

[String Format Specifiers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html)