# Passing data to another ViewController in Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uinavigationcontroller, segue

Before I begin, let me say that I have taken a look at a popular post on the matter: [Passing Data between View Controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers?rq=1)

My project is on github https://github.com/model3volution/TipMe

I am inside of a UINavigationController, thus using a `push`segue.

I have verified that my `IBAction` methods are properly linked up and that `segue.identifier` corresponds to the segue's identifier in the storyboard.

If I take out the `prepareForSegue:` method then the segue occurs, but obviously without any data updating.

My specific error message is: `Could not cast value of type 'TipMe.FacesViewController' (0x10de38) to 'UINavigationController' (0x1892e1c).`

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
// Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    if segue.identifier == "toFacesVC" {
        let navController:UINavigationController = segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController
        let facesVC = navController.topViewController as! FacesViewController
        facesVC.balanceLabel.text = "Balance before tip: $\(balanceDouble)"
    }

}
```

Below is a screenshot with the code and error.
side notes: using Xcode 6.3, Swift 1.2
[image: screen shot with code and error]

Comment: As another comment already suggested: include code within your question. I did that for you now because providing the project to download somewhere enables other users to help you much easier. I like that :) +1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of things:

1: change your `prepareForSegue` to

```
if segue.identifier == "toFacesVC" {
    let facesVC = segue.destinationViewController as! FacesViewController
    facesVC.text = "Balance before tip: $\(balanceDouble)"
}
```

2: add a string variable to your `FacesViewController`

```
var text:String!
```

3: change the `FacesViewController` `viewDidLoad`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    balanceLabel.text = text
}
```

The reasons for all the changes: the segue `destinationViewController` is the actual `FacesViewController` you transition to -> no need for the navigationController shenanigans. That alone will remove the "case error", but another will occur due to unwrapping a nil value because you try to access the `balanceLabel` which will not have been set yet. Therefore you need to create a string variable to hold the string you actually want to assign and then assign that text in the `viewDidLoad` - at the point where the `UILabel` is actually assigned.

Proof that it works:

[image]

4: If you want display two decimal places for the balance you might change the String creation to something like (following https://stackoverflow.com/a/24102844/2442804):

```
facesVC.text =  String(format: "Balance before tip: $%.2f", balanceDouble)
```

resulting in:

[image]

Comment: I think he wants it to be "$4.00" instead of "$4.0". I don't know how to do it in Swift, but in Objective C it's this to return an `NSString` object: `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Balance before tip: $.2f", balanceDouble]`

Comment: might be, don´t know, has nothing to do with his actual question though. And I do not know any way to do that within the string literal `\(...)`

Comment: I know it didn't have much to do with the OP's question but I was just looking at the screenshot and the "$4.0" annoyed me a bit.

Comment: @DDPWNAGE Okay, for completion sake I will include it ;)

Comment: @luk2302 Thanks a ton! I suppose the only question I'm left with is why would one access the navigation controller (as I did) if it seems--at least in this case,  unnecessary? My perception was that whenever a view controller was embedded in a navigation controller, you had to access the navigation controller first...though I now see that's not the case. Care to enlighten?

Comment: you only have to access the navigation controller if you push a navigation Controller, e.g. from within a tabbar controller. while you are inside a navigation controller / its navigation stack, you will always access the actual controller that will be presented. if you need more info than that i sadly can´t help you ...

Comment: @luk2302 ah, answers my question perfectly! Thanks!