# Xcode Swift Making an amount of money

Tags: swift, nsnumberformatter

I have this code that prints out an amount of money, but sometimes if the amount comes out to a multiple of 10 cents, like $22.50 or $189.20, the UI will chop off the last 0 to show $22.5 or $189.2?

```
@IBAction func btnCalPress(sender: AnyObject) {
    let tipPer = Double(PercentTip.text!)! / 100
    let billAmt = Double(BillAmount.text!)
    let salesTax = Double(SalesTax.text!)! / 100

    let tipAmt = Double(billAmt! * tipPer)
    let taxAmt = Double(billAmt! * salesTax)
    let totalAmt = tipAmt + taxAmt + billAmt!

    let tipAmountFormat = round(tipAmt * 100) / 100
    let taxAmountFormat = round(taxAmt * 100) / 100
    let totalPayFormat = round(totalAmt * 100) / 100

    TipAmount.text = "Tip: $\(tipAmountFormat)"
    TaxAmount.text = "Tax: $\(taxAmountFormat)"
    TotalAmount.text = "Total: $\(totalPayFormat)"
}
```

Comment: This is because 8 8.0 and 8.00 and 8.000 and 8.0000 are exactly the same Double. read this question for answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24051314/precision-string-format-specifier-in-swift

`String(format:"%.2f",tipAmountFormat)`

Comment: ***When dealing with currency, or numbers that require base ten, you should use NSDecimal/NSDecimalNumber.***

Answer (score 3):

When dealing with currencies it's easier to rely on `NSNumberFormatter`, which happens to also deal with some currencies specificities.

Applied to your code it would be :

```
@IBAction func btnCalPress(sender: AnyObject) {
    let tipPer = Double(PercentTip.text!)! / 100
    let billAmt = Double(BillAmount.text!)!
    let salesTax = Double(SalesTax.text!)! / 100

    let tipAmt = Double(billAmt * tipPer)
    let taxAmt = Double(billAmt * salesTax)
    let totalAmt = tipAmt + taxAmt + billAmt

    let formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
    formatter.numberStyle = .CurrencyStyle

    let tipAmount = formatter.stringFromNumber(tipAmt)!
    let taxAmount = formatter.stringFromNumber(taxAmt)!
    let totalAmount = formatter.stringFromNumber(totalAmt)!

    TipAmount.text = "Tip: \(tipAmount)"
    TaxAmount.text = "Tax: \(taxAmount)"
    TotalAmount.text = "Total: \(totalAmount)"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like @jtbandes says, you should use `NSDecimalNumber` when dealing with currencies, not `Double` or `Float`, otherwise you will lose precision.

Although floating point types can store large numbers:

```
print(FLT_MAX)    // 3.40282e+38
print(DBL_MAX)    // 1.79769313486232e+308
```

They are not suited to currencies because if you have an amount with a large number of decimal places, you will lose precision:

```
let amountString = "9999999999.000009"

let amountDouble = Double(amountString)!
print(amountDouble) 
// prints 9999999999.00001 notice how the .000009 was rounded up to .00001

let amountDecimalNumber = NSDecimalNumber(string: amountString)
print(amountDecimalNumber) // prints 9999999999.000009 no precision lost
```

When dealing with currencies, there is no excuse to lose precision, over millions of transactions, small rounding errors do add up! 
**Only round for presentation.**

```
let formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
formatter.numberStyle = .CurrencyStyle
let prettyAmount = formatter.stringFromNumber(amountDecimalNumber)
// prints $9,999,999,999.00
```