# How to format 2 decimals Double type on swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have Double value is 7.92021 and I want to change it to 7.92 (Double type).
I was try 3 methods but all not worked!

**Code 1:**

```
let d1:Double = 7.92012
let d2 = Double(String(format: ".2f", d1)) 
// the result d2 = 7.92000000000002
```

**Code 2:**

```
let d1:Double = 7.92012
let value = NSDecimalNumber(double: d1)
value.decimalNumberByAdding(2)
let result = value.doubleValue
// the result = 7.92000000000002
```

**Code 3:**

```
let d1:Double = 7.92012
let d2 = round( d1 * 100 ) / 100
// d2 = 7.92000000000002
```

How I make the result value is 7.92 (double type)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26158006/4601170

Comment: The 3rd code snippet works perfectly fine. I don't see why you are facing a problem there.

Comment: It depends upon what you want to do this this result. If the intent is merely to show it in the UI, then convert to a string with `NSNumberFormatter` (which is like `String(format:)`, but is localized). If you plan on doing arithmetic with it later, use `NSDecimalNumber`, not `Double`.

Comment: Understand the difference between a decimal and a string. Only a string can have a limited number of decimal digits.

Comment: @Sulthan - Strings aren't the _only_ way to have limited decimal points. This is what `NSDecimalNumber` is designed to solve. But, yes, in general, if merely showing the result in the UI, then a string representation is often the easiest solution.

Comment: @Rob Every decimal number, even `NSDecimalNumber` still has fractional digits. You can make them zero by rounding but you can't make them go away. The string conversion is the one that removes zero fractional digits.

Comment: @Sulthan I think 'NSDecimalNumber' designed to solve limited number of decimal. But I just want a double value because a string not for the calculation.

Comment: @BaoTuanDiep: A binary floating point number **CANNOT** represent the number `7.92` exactly. A must-read is http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html.

Comment: @MartinR: Ok I see. So what did NSDecimalNumber made?

Comment: @Sulthan - `NSDecimalNumber` is not a binary floating point number. It consists of an integer mantissa and integer exponent.