# swift: percentage of download

Tags: ios, swift

I want to get percentage of download in label. I use this code:

```
cell.label?.text = "\( (CGFloat(totalBytesWritten) / CGFloat(totalBytesExpectedToWrite)) * 100)"
```

But in this case I get numbers of percentage after the point.

I tried to use different code but it not help:

```
cell.label?.text = "\( (Int(totalBytesWritten) / Int(totalBytesExpectedToWrite)) * 100)"
```

How to get percentage like this `98%` and not like this `98.5353457%`?

Comment: `cell.label?.text = "\(Int( (totalBytesWritten/totalBytesExpectedToWrite) * 100))"`?

Comment: @Larme I get 0 when download start or 100 if download completed. Not numbers in progress.

Comment: This may be of use. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24051314/precision-string-format-specifier-in-swift

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
let progress = Float(totalBytesWritten) / Float(totalBytesExpectedToWrite)
progressLabel.text = String(format: "%.0f%%", progress * 100)
```

Comment: I have edited my solution just try now it must work. I have tested it.

Answer (score 1):

Try `Int(CGFloat(totalBytesWritten) / CGFloat(totalBytesExpectedToWrite) * 100.0)`

Comment: I get 0 or 100 if download completed.