# How to round a double to the third digit after decimal point

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a problem, I need to round a double using the third digit after decimal point. Example: 16373.89732 -> because the number is 7( the third digit) It needs to became 16373.90. if it was < 5 nothing will need to happen, it will remain 16373.89.

`let tempEndwert = ((1000*endwert).rounded())/1000` - I trie the but it is not working - 49263792.69752127 - this is the number. I need to save it formatted (49263792.70) - when rounded.

Comment: Try removing a 0. `let tempEndwert = ((100*endwert).rounded())/100` = `49263792.7`

Comment: @Martin Kostadinov You are free to use the search box at the top to find similar topics to help yourself.

Comment: What is your desired output? A rounded double value that you need to use for further computation or is it a string that you will display or insert into some data like JSON?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rounding a double value to x number of decimal places in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27338573/rounding-a-double-value-to-x-number-of-decimal-places-in-swift)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by

```
extension Formatter {
    static let number = NumberFormatter()
}

extension FloatingPoint {
    var asNumberString : String {
        Formatter.number.minimumFractionDigits = 2
        Formatter.number.maximumFractionDigits = 2
        Formatter.number.roundingMode = .halfEven
        Formatter.number.numberStyle = .decimal
        return Formatter.number.string(for: self) ?? ""
    }
}
```

Now You can  test like

150.51581.asNumberString === > "150.52" 
 150.5141531.asNumberString === > "150.51"

Comment: The same question with different answers can be found here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24051314/precision-string-format-specifier-in-swift

Answer (score 0):

Convert the Double to String upto decimal places as per requirement. You can directly save String instead of Double, i.e.

```
let num = 16373.89732
let str = String(format: "%.2f", num)
print(str) //16373.90
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let number = 49263792.69752127
let numberRounded = String(format: "%.2f", (number * 100).rounded() / 100)
```

If you are trying to save your number as String the result will be "49263792.70"

However just by rounding it and store it somewhere as Double will result in storing 49263792.7