# Localize file with property in swift

Tags: ios, swift, localization

I need to transfer the double variable to the localization file, if I write %d I can only pass int, but I need to pass the double

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Precision String Format Specifier In Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24051314/precision-string-format-specifier-in-swift)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the double with format string `%f`. To restrict the number of digits after the decimal point you can format is like this `%0.2f`. This will allow only 2 digits after the decimal point.

Sample Code:

```
let num = 10.5

let outputStr = String(format:"I am printing %0.1f", arguments:[num])

print(outputStr)
```