# How can I change time format of a label ? Swift

Tags: swift, time, timer, uilabel

In my App I want to show the user the Time he needed. At the moment it looks like this:
[image]
This is the actual code:

```
if counter <= 59.0 {
            resultTimeLabel.text = String(format: "%.1", counter)
            resultTimeLabel.text = "in \(counter) seconds"
        }
        if counter >= 60.0 {
            let minutes = counter / 60.0
            resultTimeLabel.text = String(format: "%.1", counter)
            resultTimeLabel.text = "in \(minutes) minutes"
```

Which format is the right one to make it looks like: 1.5 and not 1.5000000023

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Precision String Format Specifier In Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24051314/precision-string-format-specifier-in-swift)

Comment: No absolutely not but thank's

Comment: That's strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue there is that you are assigning a new string over the previous formatted string and it is missing an "f" in your string format:

```
if counter < 60 {
    resultTimeLabel.text = "in " + String(format: "%.1f", counter) + " seconds"
}
else 
if counter >= 60 {
    let minutes = counter / 60.0
    resultTimeLabel.text = "in " + String(format: "%.1f", minutes) + " minutes"
```